# Data Modeling: vehicle's year, make, and model?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm trying to model vehicles at a basic level. Here's how I see the data:

- A "year" (e.g. 2010, 2011) has 0 or more "make" (e.g. Nissan, Honda)
- A "make" has 0 or more "model" (e.g. Nissan has Sentra, Altima, Maxima)

It wouldn't make sense to have a "year" table containing just 1 column, so I think it would be combined with "make" to create:

```
TABLE: year_make
- year
- make
```

I guess that "year" and "make" columns would make up a composite key.

Then I would have a "model" table that somehow is associated to "year_make" table. The problem is that I don't know what in "year_make" to put in "model" to associate the 2 tables.

Do I make a PK: year_make->year_make_id and use that? It would mean that "year" and "make" columns no longer make a composite key, right?

**UPDATE:**

I suppose I should have a lookup table "lookup_make", then "year_make" would have a "lookup_make_id" instead of "make" column.

**UPDATE 2:**

Per nate c:

```
TABLE: make
 - make_id
 - name

TABLE: model
 - model_id
 - make_id
 - name

TABLE: model_year
 - model_id
 - year
```

Comment: A year does not have an attribute of car model (in normal usage). But, a model has an attribute of year. Compare sentences:  The Ford Escort was made in 1996. The year 2004 'put plausible verb clause here' Ford Escort.

Comment: @ sonewbie: Your new way is modelling a many-to-many join. Which can be said in English something like 'A model can have many years, and also a year can have many models.' The learning example for these is usually something like employee-project: 'An employee can belong to many projects, and a project can have many employees.' Most people probably would not model years this way. A year is usually a measurement of some object - not an object in its own right. and The answers below seem  like a fairly sane/regular way to do things. But there is not one true way.

Comment: @nate, but does the latest model work? No chance of duplicate data, right? I can also query for "what makes are available for a particular year?", "what models are available for a particular year?", or "what models are available for a particular year/make?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at some more I think you are right to model the year as a many to many join. I put both ways just to show as examples of what of I am talking about. If you have an attribute that covers the whole model over years such as car class (economy, truck, luxury, etc.) You would need a many to many table for normalization and to avoid data duplication.

```
    -- id did not use auto-incs as I am just showing the relational model

    create table make(
            makename        varchar                         primary key
    );
    -- 1.  many to many
    create table model(
            modelname       varchar not null,
            makename        varchar not null        references make(makename),
            -- if carclass changes - one update changes every model/year combo
            carclass        varchar not null -- economy, suv, truck etc ...
            primary key (makename, modelname)
    );

    create table model_year(
            year            integer not null,
            modelname       varchar not null        references model(modelname)
            baseprice       integer not null
            primary key (year, modelname)
    );
    -- 2. year /w/ model
    create table model(
            modelname       varchar not null,
            makename        varchar not null        references make(makename),
            year            integer not null,
            -- update anomaly - you would have to update every model/year combo
            carclass        varchar -- economy, suv, truck etc ...
            -- baseprice is OK since it is tied to the year 
            baseprice       integer not null
            primary key (makename, modelname, year)
    );
```

... So #1 would be the more 'correct' and robust way, especially if you planning to hold attributes on the model that would be independent of what year it was made. Either way would get you the same queries. In fact, its *harder / more work* (not really after you get it down) to join the the tables of a normalized one than a non-normalized one. But that is not the point. You are putting in the DB because you want your data to be correct (I hope).

Note: those are the *real* primary keys even if you use auto-inc primary keys. You would want to change the primary keys to unique ones to ensure data consistency and change the referencing foreign keys to integers.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll be better prepared for design if you create some sample data. The goal is to come up with *representative* sample data. You can learn a lot from *representative* sample data. (And you can make some pretty expensive mistakes if your sample data isn't representative.)

```
Year  Make    Model    ??  ?????
--
2011  Honda   Accord   LX  Sedan
2011  Honda   Accord   SE  Sedan
2011  Honda   Accord   EX  Coupe
2011  Toyota  Yaris        3-door liftback
2011  Toyota  Yaris        Sedan
2011  Toyota  Yaris        5-door liftback
2011  Lexus   IS 350       Sedan
2011  Lexus   IS 250       Sedan
```

- What should you call the ? columns?
- Do "Yaris" and "IS 350" belong in the
  same column?
- Do "IS" and "350" belong in two different columns?
- What do you do about columns that don't apply to all models?

Resist the temptation to throw a handful of id numbers at data like this. Identify keys and functional dependencies first. Normalize based on the keys and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you would need to create one `make` table and one `model` table.
The `model` table would have columns for `id`, `make_id`, `name`, `year`.

Obviously, make_id would be the foreign key pointing to the `make` table.

It really depends on what your situation is and how much you would need to normalize your data.

Comment: given a year, would I be able to select all the makes for that year? Given a make, would I be able to select all the models for that make?

Comment: Yup. Rough attempt at sql, but     `SELECT * FROM model WHERE year = ?`

Comment: That should grab every row in the `model` table which contains the year you specify.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I wouldn't make a table for the years.  Doing SQL on an integer column (such as year) is incredibly fast, especially with the right indexes in place.  Much faster than a join.

However, I do see the merit to having a separate table for the Make and doing join based on that.  This way you'd be able to enter manufacturer details like history, years of production, website, etc.

So I'd do:

```
Manufacturers: (or Makes)
  - id
  - name
  - website
  - country

Cars:
  - manufacturer_id (or make_id)
  - model
  - year
  - doors
  - trim_class
```

Comment: I think a model has 0 or more "trim". I was going to create another table just for "trim" and have "model_id" as a FK to "model" table.

Comment: "Make" and "Manufacturer" aren't the same thing. Toyota manufactures both Toyota and Lexus. Some makes are joint ventures between multiple manufacturers. Whether the OP needs to store additional details about a make is a good issue to bring up, though.

Comment: @stackOverflowNewbie yeah good point, just using it for filler :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks good so far, like your thinking. In the cars table though, if you have to enter Camry 2001, camry 2002 canry 2003, camree 2004. Seems like you would have redundant data along with the risk of data integrity with misspelling. IMO you would also need somekind of Entity with makeID and modelID, with modelID it is entered just once or model is just entered once in a table. 'Camry' will always be 'Camry' represented with modelID.

Comment: I've been struggling with this same project so I don't have the exact answer. But just looking at it from a normalization view, I think you need a model table with just the modelID and model(you know like Camry). Then you put that together with makeID and modelID making a composite key(for perhaps car or vehicle table), with this I think you eliminate redundant data along with misspelling. I guess what I struggle with is putting it all together so it all makes sense. make, model, trim, doors, year. I'm sure I can put it together but don't want to over engineer it. however I hate redundant data

Comment: how do I get in touch with you? Maybe we can collaborate on some aspects of the data modeling. See UPDATE 2 of my post. I think it solves the basic issues you are talking about.